# Create And Publish WFS Service With ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, wfs

The primary goal I want to reach is to have updated points every 1 minute and reflect them on the ArcGIS map using WFS Service.

I tried to publish an old table I had as a WFS Service but when I open it on the browser it doesn't show any data, and tried to create an enterprise geodatabase but couldn't add layers so I can't add points to it I think I have to edit somehow and then convert it to see just maybe.

I read something about WFS if I have an API that feeds the locations can I use it directly to update the map on a WFS Service?

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Enterprise?

Comment: yes i have ArcGIS Enterprise.

Comment: Generically, you can use a Transactional WFS (WFS-T) to edit, update, delete features provided in a WFS.  If you don't have WFS-T, then you will need to have some other mechanism to update the datasource that the WFS uses.